# cut() and label eveything in tibble by the same breaks and labels

Tags: r, automation, label, cut, tibble

I got a [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) that is 8984 times 155 where I need to `cut()` and label all all columns in the same way, i.e. using the same cut and the same labels to create a new labeled [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble). How do I do this in a simple way?

Here a 3 times 3 [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) to simulate my 8984 times 155  [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble)

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse", "lubridate"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = c(4, NA, 6))
df <- df %>% mutate(iD = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y    iD
#>   <int> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1  4.00     1
#> 2     2 NA        2
#> 3     3  6.00     3
```

Now, I currently label it like this, I realize I can creta a `breaks` objcet and a  `labels` object and reuse them, but isen't there a way in whch I can away repeating the `mutate()` call?

```
df_labeled <-  df %>% mutate(x = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf,1,3,6),
   labels = c('Low', 'middle', 'high'), include.lowest = TRUE),
                             y = cut(y, breaks = c(-Inf,1,3,6),
   labels = c('Low', 'middle', 'high'), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
                                                                 select(iD, x, y)
```

This gives me what I want, but I am looking for a more general way.

```
df_labeled
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      iD x      y    
#>   <int> <fct>  <fct>
#> 1     1 Low    high 
#> 2     2 middle <NA> 
#> 3     3 middle high
```

p.s. am I the only one who gets an error when I call my id variable `id`?

Inspired by [jazzurro's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842249/cut-and-label-eveything-in-tibble-by-the-same-matrics?noredirect=1#comment84688653_48842249) I am currently experimenting with this

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-iD),cut(as.numeric(.), breaks = c(-Inf,1,3,6), 
            labels = c('Low', 'middle', 'high'), include.lowest = TRUE))
```

but I still get an error,

```
Error in cut(as.numeric(.), breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 3, 6), labels = c("Low",  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I'm currently reading teh manual to figuring that one out.

Comment: Seeing your code, it seems to me that you want to use either `mutate_all()` or `mutate_at()`. If you do that, you do not have to type the same `cut()` line for all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your difficulty applying [jazzurro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304471/jazzurro)'s comment is because you don't need `as.numeric(.)`:

```
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-iD), cut, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 3, 6), include.lowest = TRUE,
              labels = c('Low', 'middle', 'high'))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
       x      y    iD
  <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1    Low   high     1
2 middle   <NA>     2
3 middle   high     3
```